# jQuery UI - Dialog when resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dialog

I'm using dynamic element and iframe for dialog functionality

```
$( '<div id="dialog"><iframe src="myHtml.html"></iframe></div>').dialog();
```

The problem:
When trying to re-size to smaller size than iFrame can be the mouse is 'captured' and continuing to re-size even when the button is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue tracked in [**Dialog cannot be dragged properly with IFRAME**](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7650)